# Debouncing an action when changing Input value

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, debouncing

I'm trying to debounce an action when the value of an Input element is changed. This action is captured by a saga and an HTTP request is made.
First I've tried to do:

```
<Input
  name='name'
  value={this.props.finish.name}
  placeholder='Ex: My application'
  onChange={event => this.saveAppName(event.target.name, event.target.value)}
/>

private saveAppName = debounce((name: string, value: string) => {
  if (value.length) {
    this.props.dispatch(changeInputFinish({name, value}));
  }
}, 500);
```

The solution above worked but I can't type fast into the Input. If I do then the Input doesn't capture everything.

After that I've tried to change "saveAppName" method to:

```
private saveAppName = (name: string, value: string) => {
  if (value.length) {
    debounce(this.props.dispatch(changeInputFinish({name, value})), 500);
  }
}
```

The code above allows me to type anything as fast as I want inside the Input element but ends up retrieving an error and crashing the application. The error the is shown is "TypeError: Expected a function". It is an error from lodash debounce. It expects a function but the action "changeInputFinish({name, value})" returns an action object and not a function.

To try to solve this issue I've tried to make the action return a new function instead of an action object with the code below:

```
private saveAppName = (name: string, value: string) => {
  if (value.length) {
    debounce(() => this.props.dispatch(changeInputFinish({name, value})), 500);
  }
}
```

The code above doesn't retrieve any error but it doesn't let me type anything inside the Input, then I don't know if it's really the solution.

Does anyone know how can I solve this issue? Basically, I need to debounce an action that is captured by a saga that makes http requests. Should I try to debounce on my saga and not on my component since I'm trying to improve the performance of my HTTP requests?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the function returned by debounce:

```
handleChange = event => _.debounce(() => {
    this.saveAppName(event.target.name, event.target.value)
}, 150);

...

<Input
  name='name'
  value={this.props.finish.name}
  placeholder='Ex: My application'
  onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

Tim

P.S. It's an anti-pattern to send inline closures as a prop to a subcomponent, since they'll be recreated for each render, forcing a re-render of the subcomponent too (since the props will have changed). You should create your function once and pass that same function each time, as I've done here.